# Javascript storing image in an object in an array, is there in console.log(), but when logging the object?

Tags: javascript, arrays, image, object

I have a problem that I am not able to understand.

I have an array of objects, the properties for each object in the array are id, source, and cache. The id is an identifier, the source is the source of a file, and the cache is the actual file.

When I console log the whole array I get the following output;

```
console.log(array);

[Object]
    0: Object
        cache: img
        id: "strawberry"
        source: "http://127.0.0.1/images/strawberry.png"
```

It clearly shows the array has one index of 0 which is an object. The object has a cache property which is an image object, an id which is strawberry and source, the source of the image.

My problem is trying to retrieve the cache image object. After testing I found that if I console log the actual index of 0 rather than the whole array I get;

```
console.log(array[0]);

Object {id: "strawberry", source: "http://127.0.0.1/images/strawberry.png"}
```

You can see the cache has disappeared? I do not understand this?

If it matters I am coding using strict.

Could anyone please explain why this is happening?

**Setting cache like so**

```
var Assets = function (assets) {

     this.assets = assets;
};

Assets.prototype.load = function () {

    // For each asset
    this.assets.forEach(function (asset, index) {
        // Create new image object
        var img = new Image();
        // Image load handler
        img.addEventListener("load", function () {
            // Add image to assets
            this.assets[index].cache = img;
        }.bind(this), false);
        // Set the image source
        img.src = this.assets[index].source;
    }, this);
};

var assets = new Assets([{id: "strawberry", source: "http://127.0.0.1/images/strawberry.png"}]);

assets.load();

console.log(assets.assets); // shows cache image obj

console.log(assets.assets[0]); // show no cache
```

Comment: @MichaelGeary JSON will not show the image object.

Comment: @CarlG have you tried `console.log(array[0].cache)`?

Comment: I get undefined?! I can upload it to a web server so you can see?

Comment: Better idea: Instead of `console.log`, put a `debugger;` statement in your code, and when it stops use the interactive debugger to inspect your variables.

Comment: How are you setting the cache property?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Umm... **because it's not there *yet***?

If you do something like:

```
setTimeout(function() {
    console.log(assets.assets[0]); // show cache
}, 1000); // adjust accordingly
```

then you will see `cache`. ;)

The line `this.assets[index].cache = img;` won't be executed until the image has been loaded and due to the asynchronous nature of JavaScript, your `console.log` might be executed earlier, giving you the *undefined* result.

I am pretty sure that you got:

```
[Object]
    0: Object
        cache: img
        id: "strawberry"
        source: "http://127.0.0.1/images/strawberry.png"
```

after clicking on some expand button (>) in the console. Just before you did this action, the image actually had finished loading and you could therefore see the `cache`.

For the `assets.assets[0]`, however, the whole `Object {id: "strawberry", source: "http://127.0.0.1/images/strawberry.png"}` was logged before the image had been loaded and thus you didn't see the `cache`.

So I believe what actually happened was:

1. The `console.log(assets.assets)` printed out `> [Object]`, the `cache` was not there yet actually but you didn't notice this because it was hidden/collapsed.
2. The `console.log(assets.assets[0])` printed out `Object {id: "strawberry", source: "http://127.0.0.1/images/strawberry.png"}`, the `cache` wasn't there as well.
3. The image was loaded and attached to `cache`.
4. You clicked on the '>', expanding the `[Object]` printed out by `console.log(assets.assets)`, and saw `cache` there, because it's now already there.

Comment: Thanks for clearing this up. I never knew the console auto updated itself like that. I though when I logged something it was as is. Thank you again.

Comment: @CarlG No problem, glad that it helped. :) (I was actually quite "amused" when I first encountered it several months ago while debugging my colleague's code.)